# How to hide information in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, rules, angularfire, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

I have these requirements:

1. User will log in via email and multiple Oauth providers. I use function like `User.findByEmail('1@1.com')`. So I need to have permision to see the list of users before being authenticated.
2. User's email address, geolocation and age should be kept secretly from other users.

My first plan was:

> ```
> users:{
>   $user-id:{
>
> //  public
>     ".read" : true,
>     name,
>     created_at,
>
>     private: {
>         ".read" : "auth.email === data.child('email').val()",
>         age,
>         email,
>         geolocation,
>     }
>     $piority = email
>   }
> }
> ```

Then I realized no, it just doesn't work that way. So would anyone please tell me how to do it correctly? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Firebase really needs a filter/serialize method.

Comment: That sounds like you need a 'super admin' user role... Why would you need the list of all users? Why user cannot login first and then get access to its own data?

Comment: Good question. Well in sign up form, I have set it to check if email exists when the email address is `on blur`. Besides this, users indeed always sign in with `Auth` before using `User.findByEmail()`. However, the real problem is that after user got `Auth`, he needs to load current user from User "table". The User table uses user-id as key and email address as priority. So I have to use `equalTo` query to get `User.findByEmail()`. If I hide some of the info in User, I will have banned the `equalTo` query.

Comment: Well, if the user's email is the primary key to access user data, why don't you use email instead of $user-id.

Comment: I want to keep email secret. It will be irrespective to show a personal email address in a user's profile page URL. I was looking for a way to hide $priority too. But now it seems like there is no way to do so. Ok, let's say I would give it up and expose users' email address to the public. How do I keep the rests, such as geolocation, age and facebook token in secret under User tree? In future, I will have some more complicated models like Company tree, which has different permissions to diff users to see its diff parts of info. Thus I want to know if there is a right way to do it.

Comment: Do I have to create one more redundant tree each time I create a new user group, so these user groups won't see each other's secret data?

Comment: I didn't suggest exposing user email to the public, in fact even telling user during registration that such email already registered in a bad practice from security point of view. However, you can restrict user data to logged in user only: .read":  "auth != null". Firebase has been built for lightning performance and normalization is your enemy here. Try to design the DB structure with access by primary key only in mind. If it requires redundant data - so be it. If you tell us more about the application and data structure you are building, we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61250/discussion-between-ivan-wang-and-alexander-burakevych).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really several questions in this post. The first is how to store private data. One simple change you can make is to invert the public/private and user keys--they don't have to be nested in the same user record.

```
/users/$user_id/...public data...
/private/$user_id/...private data...
```

This makes securing the data quite a bit simpler.

Another question is regarding duplicate email detection. If we assume you are using simple login here, this is all pretty moot. You can check to see if an email address exists by simply trying to create the account. An error will be returned if the email is already registered.

If that doesn't solve it, you can still check this manually, without providing a list of users' emails. This is typically done with an index. When a new account is created, write something like this:

```
/email_index/$escaped_email/$userid ($userid is the value)
```

Now when you want to check if the email is available, you do a read like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
function checkEmail(emailAddress, callback) {
   ref.child('email_index/'+escapeEmail(emailAddress)).once('value', function(snap) {
       callback(snap.val() !== null);
   });
}

function escapeEmail(emailAddress) {
   return (email || '').replace('.', ',');
}

checkEmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, function(exists) {
   console.log(EMAIL_ADDRESS + (exists? 'does' : 'does not') + ' exist!');
 });
```

To prevent someone from listing the emails, you do something like this in your (amazingly flexible and really quite sophisticated, even for enterprise apps) security rules:

```
"email_index": {
   // no .read rule here means that the data cannot be listed; I have to know the email address to check it
   "$email_address": {
       ".read": true,
       // it can only be claimed once and the value must be my user id
       ".write": "auth.uid === newData.val() && !data.exists()"
   }
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, what should be the security rule for `/public/$user_id/...public data...`'s `write`? Note it will not have email address in public data.

Comment: Probably just something like "auth.uid === $user_id"?

Comment: Well that will do if I use auth.uid as user id. I do use uid but I have got rid of the prefix of uid. So instead of `"simple-login: 123"`, it is just `"123"`. Is there any way I can strip the prefix in security rule too?

Comment: `auth.id` should work in that case, depending on the provider. You may need to use custom auth tokens if you've used a proprietary number.